# Load data relevant to Id which store in local storage Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm saving my company Id in local storage. when a client visit to branch page I need to show branches which relate to company is stored in local storage. Currently it's showing all branches.

My select compnay dropdown is in another component and my table is in another component.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.getBranches();
 }

  getBranches() {
      let id: number;
      id = +localStorage.getItem('cid');
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('cid'));
      this.branchService.getBranches().subscribe(x => {
         Object.assign(this.branchData, x);
         this.branchData = this.branchData.filter(b => b.CompanyId = id);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `localStorage`, it's in the subscribtion.
`this.branchData = this.branchData.filter(b => b.CompanyId = id);`
That line is causing the problem.

I'd suggest:

```js
branchData: any; // Or an defined Entity

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.getBranches();
}

getBranches() {
 this.branchService.getBranches
  .pipe(filter(data => data.CompanyId === +localStorage.getItem('cid'))
  .subscibe(data => this.branchData = data);
}
```

If you use branchData inside the DOM I recommend using the async pipe and set it like that

```
branchData: Observable<any>;

...
getBranches() {
 this.branchData = this.branchService.getBranches
  .pipe(filter(data => data.CompanyId === +localStorage.getItem('cid'));
}

// inside DOM

<p>{{(branchData | async)?.CompanyId}}</p>
```

Haven't tested it, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for ur time. but it not working. I tried

Comment: what does happens? Are you sure `data.CompanyId` is a number? try the same filter with `==`. Otherwise log all branches you get and check manually if the company you are looking for even exist.

Comment: I tried but it's not showing data. I have branches it belongs to company

Comment: If `branchService.getBranches()` returns only an empty Observable, your request is probably wrong